# Spark 1.6.0 DenseMatrix update values

Tags: matrix, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

There was Update method in Spark 1.3.1

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/DenseMatrix.html

But in Spark 1.6.0, there is no Update method

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/DenseMatrix.html

My idea is to store large set of elements in a distributed matrix and perform operation on that, How to update values in DenseMatrix ??

Any example or suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

1. `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseMatrix` - is not a distributed data structure but a local one, implemented using plain Java arrays. If you're looking for a local data structures which can be efficiently updated consider using [Breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze)
2. distributed matrices ([`mllib.linalg.distributed.DistributedMatrix`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.DistributedMatrix)) are, same as other distributed data structures in Spark, immutable.

Comment: Thanks for update, i checked docs: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html#local-matrix , Lets say, if i use **DenseMatrix**, then how should i update its elements.

Comment: You shouldn't :) Theoretically you can modify Java array directly but don't do it.